# Could not connect to wss

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I want to add websockets chat to my Django (DRF) application. I am following this tutorial
https://dev.to/earthcomfy/django-channels-a-simple-chat-app-part-3-a3b

My versions

```
django-rest-passwordreset==1.2.1
channels==3.0.5
channels-redis==3.4.1
```

Nginx configuration **What should I add for websockets?**

```
upstream app {
    server django:8800;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:8800;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    }
    ...
```

Routing

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

I have a standard consumer:

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

I am sending request wss://localhost:6060/ws/chat/r1

On the server side I see logs:

```
nginx_1      | 172.18.0.1 - - [28/Sep/2022:19:55:22 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03<\xA1\xCE\xACW\x06T\x84\x1F\xE3\x13\xD8F\x00\x03\x11\xC3><4k~_\x14\x83j=\xD1}u^R '\xCE\xF3\xB2\x142\x84+J~\xEC\xDAG?c\xD0)q\xBDZ\xD9\x95_\x1C\xED\x83L,\x1C" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

But have the following error. **How to fix it?**
[image]

Comment: For one, your re_path ends with a slash so the correct URL would be `wss://localhost:6060/ws/chat/r1/`

Comment: Thank, fixed, but result is the same. I  just found out that the problem deals with Ngingx configuration